# Can an ideal fluid be at rest in a non conservative body force field?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

We know that, when an ideal fluid is at rest, then the body force density is equal to the gradient of the pressure. But, that means body force should be conservative. So, does it mean fluid can't be at rest in non conservative body force field?

Comment: does friction count as non conservative? Because I doubt it compels a fluid to move.

Comment: Yes, it is non conservative. But, it only acts at the interface i.e. a surface force